# Spinner Json e ArrayList

Tags: json, web-service, arraylist

Estou começando no desenvolvimento Android e estou com uma duvida tensa aqui. Eu tenho de retorno um Json assim:

```
[
   {
      "codTransportadora":295,
      "NomeTransportadora":"UTILISSIMO",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":1122,
      "NomeTransportadora":"UNILOG",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":273,
      "NomeTransportadora":"COOPERCARGA",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":352,
      "NomeTransportadora":"PATRUS",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":364,
      "NomeTransportadora":"FEDEX",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":516,
      "NomeTransportadora":"TRANSMAGNA",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":982,
      "NomeTransportadora":"OTD",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":1083,
      "NomeTransportadora":"KGT",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":1834,
      "NomeTransportadora":"TOMBINI",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":2367,
      "NomeTransportadora":"RAPIDO MAXEXPRESS",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":2382,
      "NomeTransportadora":"SETTOR",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":2636,
      "NomeTransportadora":"REITER",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":3938,
      "NomeTransportadora":"PATRUS TRANSPORTES URGENTES",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":6868,
      "NomeTransportadora":"SEQUOIA",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":7045,
      "NomeTransportadora":"IBL",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":7334,
      "NomeTransportadora":"GENEROSO",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":7340,
      "NomeTransportadora":"DV3",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":7344,
      "NomeTransportadora":"ENTREGA FACIL EXPRESS",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":7347,
      "NomeTransportadora":"TGESTIONA",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":7348,
      "NomeTransportadora":"RODOFLY",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":3366,
      "NomeTransportadora":"SANTINI",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":6374,
      "NomeTransportadora":"LOGIC LOGISTICA",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":294,
      "NomeTransportadora":"FASSINA",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":1472,
      "NomeTransportadora":"TRANSPOSERVS",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":7404,
      "NomeTransportadora":"SERVPORTO",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":3116,
      "NomeTransportadora":"ALDA TRANSPORTES",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":843,
      "NomeTransportadora":"CAMILO",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":7023,
      "NomeTransportadora":"LETSARA",
      "codEmpresa":3122
   },
   {
      "codTransportadora":6863,
      "NomeTransportadora":null,
      "codEmpresa":3122
   }
]
```

É uma lista de Transportadoras, no método da URL, eu apenas entro com o `CodEmpresa`.

Sendo assim, eu preciso pegar os valores dos campos `NomeTransportadora` e alimentar o meu Spinner. Como eu poderia fazer isto?

Fiz o seguinte:

```
Type type2 = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Get_Transportadora>>() {
                                        }.getType();
                                        final List<Get_Transportadora> objectsList = new Gson().fromJson(send.getResponse(), type2);

                                        ArrayAdapter<String>arrayAdapter;
                                        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,);

                                        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,****"Aqui eu creio que deveria passar o meu -objectsList-" mas continua dando erro***);
                                         spinner_transp.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu aconselharia usar a lib **Jackson** (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core)

você pode criar uma classe que represente o que vem do servidor, e a lib transforma pra vc em um objeto JAVA
btw aqui (https://github.com/BeholderDEV/MagicRBC/tree/master/MagicAPIBot) tem um exemplo de como usei isso pra fazer algo parecido com cartinhas, mas seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
public class Transportadora{
    private int codTransportadora;
    private String NomeTransportadora;
    private int codEmpresa;

    // getters e setters
}
```

dai :

```
public class TransportadorasCollection {
    private Transportadora[] transportadoras;

    public Transportadora[] getTransportadoras() {
        return transportadoras;
    }

    public void setTransportadoras(Transportadora[] transportadoras) {
        this.transportadoras= transportadoras;
    }

}
```

e depois:

```
public void run(){
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES, false);
        try {

            TransportadorasCollection cl = mapper.readValue(new File("/caminho"), TransportadorasCollection .class)
         .....
        }
```

Enfim; a documentação da lib ajuda tb